# npm ERR! errno -4058 while running npm run start-rewired

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I run my React app using `npm` using the following command `npm run start-rewired`.
However, in doing so, I'm getting the below error:

```
> project@0.1.0 start-rewired
> react-app-rewired start

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\project
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{my-user}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-16T15_34_33_074Z-debug-0.log
```

I have followed a lot of the suggestions online, including deleting the `node_modules` as well as clearing the npm cache using `npm cache clean`

I'm running `npm run start-rewired` in the root path of my project. I should mention that I use `yarn` to install the dependencies and packages, and that running `yarn install` worked fine.

I'm really stuck and I'm unsure on what to do at this point.

**EDIT** I should also mention that this project starts up fine on a different machine with the same `node` and `npm` versions.

Comment: What happen if you run `yarn start-rewired`?

Comment: I get this: `error Couldn't find the binary react-app-rewired start`

Comment: After deleting `node_modules`, did you run `yarn` and then `yarn start-rewired`?

Comment: Yep, I've just done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was due to the fact that `npm` couldn't find the `bash.exe` location for git. It was looking here `C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe` but git was installed in a different location. So what I did was uninstall and reinstall git in the above location and it resolved the issue.